# django-tastypie to have JSON response

Tags: django, tastypie

What I meant exactly was, I would like to have JSON response when I modify the obj_create(). I've implemented the UserSignUpResource(ModelResource) and inside the obj_create(), I did some validation and when it fails, I raise BadRequest(). However, this doesn't throw out JSON. It throws out String instead.

Any idea if I can make it throw out {'error': 184, 'message': 'This username already exists'} format? Or am I not suppose to modify obj_create()? Or what should I do instead?

Many help, thanks.

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: I had the same issue in django-piston, where the convenience error response types were plain html responses. I had to wrap them in my own custom `JsonResponse` that would reformat it.

Answer (score 2):

easy that, i've just created a little helper method in tastypies http module:

```
import json

#tastypies HttpResponse classes here...

def create_json_response(data, http_response_class):
    return http_response_class(content=json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

then you can simply say:

```
from tastypie.http import HttpNotFound, create_json_response

#choose HttpNotFound, HttpCreated whatever...
raise ImmediateHttpResponse(create_json_response({"error":"resource not found"}, HttpNotFound))
```

Comment: I don't think creating a method on the tastypie http module is a good ideia here. If you really need to create it do it in some helper module of yours, not on tastypie (although I dont't think you need it).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the error_response method from the resource.

Something like:

```
    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        # Code that finds Some error
        my_errors = {"error": ["Some error"]}
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=self.error_response(bundle.request, my_errors))
```

Usually you would call super and the errors should arise from the tastypie validation process. The exception would be automatically thrown (with the errors dictionary being saved on the bundle.errors property).